# Rod Cutting Problem Code

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming. I read articles for the rod cutting problem and I applied it in cpp, and I got a doubt, does the below code solves the problem through memoization (say, previously rod(3) was solved, then if same function was called with same parameters) has the answer, or will it use tabulation (`rodMax` array), or uses both?

Since I read two different articles explaining different methods(memoization and tabulation, and read as two different methods to solve a dynamic problem), kind of confused on which method the below code runs.

````
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b){

    if(a > b)
        return a;

    return b;
}

int arr[5] = {2, 4, 1, 2, 7};

int rodMax[5] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

int rod(int n){

    if(n <=0)
        return 0;

    if(rodMax[n - 1] != -1){
        return rodMax[n];
    }

    int max_val = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        max_val = max(max_val, arr[n-i-1]+rod(n-1));
    }
    //cout<<"\nmax "<<max_val<<endl;
    rodMax[n - 1] = max_val;

    return max_val;
}

int main() {

    cout<<"ans "<<rod(5)<<endl;
    //cout<<"ans "<<rod(3)<<endl;
    //for(int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    //  cout<<rodMax[i]<<" ";
}
```
````

Comment: Are you sure the code works? Did you test it with different use cases?

Comment: Hi Konijn, yes it works. Didn't test with many use cases. Just for implementation purpose, I read article and implemented it directly in C++.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to summarise the "rod cutting problem", for those of us who don't recognise it from your description?  Thanks.

Comment: hey Toby, actually i got confused with tabulation and optimizing the code by using array to store intermediate results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Use a consistent code style.** [Code style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) is a very important thing. It doesn't matter which one you choose, but any code style has to be *consistent*.
- **Choose appropriate names for entities.** For example, it would be better to change the name of the `rod` function to something like `cutRod`, `arr` to `prices`, and so on.
- **Pass the list of prices directly to the function.** It is better to avoid using global variables; pass the price array directly into the `cutRod` function:

  ```
  int cutRod(const int prices[], int length) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- **Don't use `std::endl` just as a new line symbol.** `std::endl` is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395960/8086115) as just `\n`. You should avoid using it globally.
- **Use appropriate type for counters that hold length of arrays**. You should not use `int` as type for variables that hold length of arrays (such as `i`) because it is not guaranteed that `int` can hold maximal size of an array. Use `std::size_t` instead.
- **Why -1?** I think it would be better to fill `rodMax` with `INT_MIN` instead of just `-1`.
- **Matter of taste, but...** You can replace

  ```
  rodMax[n - 1] = max_val;
  return max_val;
  ```

  by a single line

  ```
  return (rodMax[n - 1] = max_val);
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks for the review, most of them makes sense, and i'll use it. Especially for size_t, which i have used previously, and as i said it is just an quick implementation. I have a doubt @eanmos if we use  `return (rodMax[n - 1] = max_val);`, doesn't it return `true` boolean value instead of the number which is `max_val`?

Comment: @susil95, no, the `=` operator returns the new value of `rodMax[n - 1]` i. e. `max_val`. You'd be correct if we use `==` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info man. I just tried that, initially i used to think that anything with "=", will assign a value and gives an Boolean value, which is like acknowledging the statement that it ran, like `if(cout<<"hello")`, It prints `hello` and goes inside if block.

Comment: @susil95, you're welcome)

Answer (score 3):

Don't `using namespace std` - especially if you're going to define a `max()` function in the global namespace (why not just use `std::max()` anyway?  That's what it's for!).

Where do the values in `arr` and `rodMax` come from?  Do their lengths have to agree?  If so, make that obvious in the code (e.g. use `std::array`, so that we can use `arr.size()` to count the members).

Comment: Hi values for arr(price of the rod) and rodMax(maximum price obtained after cutting the rod in different size). It should have been applied by std array. But just for quick implementation i wrote this. Thanks